# Grab a text from DIV in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a DIV of the following kind:

```
 <div class='entry'>
                <p class='entry-text'>собаки играют вместе <a title="Search private" class="app-context-link" href="/contexts/private">@private</a></p>
                <p class='entry-date'>14172869383540000</p>
                <p class='entry-menu'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="app-link-menu" href="#">show filtered</a></p>
                <div class='separator'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

I have a code that takes out the contents of the DIV which looks like this below, but how do I change it so it takes out the text that's inside 'entry-text' class only?

```
  $(".entry").on('dblclick', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the statement into the edit box at the top
        $("#statement").val(e.currentTarget.innerText);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$('.entry-text').text();`

Comment: yes, that could work but the problem is that i have several of them on the page, so it should be the .entry-text within the e event

Comment: `$(this).find('.entry-text').text();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it :

```
$(".entry").on('dblclick', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the statement into the edit box at the top
    $("#statement").val($('.entry-text', e.currentTarget).text());
}
```

`$('.entry-text', e.currentTarget)` selects all elements with `entry-text` class within `e.currentTarget` element and then calls `.text()` on it.

Sources :

- [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [`$(selector, context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".entry").on('dblclick', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the statement into the edit box at the top
    $("#statement").html($('.entry-text', e.currentTarget).text());
}
```

.val() is for inputbox and forms
.html() is for selecting text

Answer (score 0):

**e.currentTarget**  is typically equals to **this** .So this also works.

```
$(".entry").on('dblclick', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the statement into the edit box at the top
    $("#statement").val($('.entry-text', this).text());
}
```